# Dynamic table with border

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I created an email alert that gets sent out once a day with a list of accounts that are getting deliveries the next day. This is working fine but since i'm using a dynamic table, some users are complaining that its hard to read without any borders.

See example:
https://ibb.co/dGTvPsG

And here's how i'm doing it:

```
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  


$a[] = $res['Order_Number'];
$b[] = $res['Detail_ShipDate'];
$c[] = $res['ShipTo_Name'];
$d[] = $res['Status'];

$Order_Number = implode("<br />", $a);
$Detail_ShipDate = implode("<br />", $b);
$ShipTo_Name = implode("<br />", $c);
$Status = implode("<br />", $d);


$for_php_mailer = '<table style="border: 1px solid black;
width: 100%;font-size: 12px!important;">

<tr>
<th>Delivery Date</th>
<th>Order#</th>
<th>Company Name</th>
<th>Status</th>

<td>'.$Detail_ShipDate.'</td>
<td>'.$Order_Number.'</td>
<td>'.$ShipTo_Name.'</td>
<td>'.$Status.'</td>

</tr>

</table>';
```

Instead of that, I need it to look like this: https://ibb.co/XsVgZWv

I tried different combinations of the following but one or two things happen. I only get 1 record from the table or an Illegal string offset error.

I'm still learning and would greatly appreciate help.

```
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  
foreach ( $res as $data ) 
{
$for_php_mailer ='
    <td>'.$data['Detail_ShipDate'].'</td>
    <td>'.$data['Order_Number'].'</td>
    <td>'.$data['ShipTo_Name'].'</td>
    <td>'.$data['Status'].'</td>';
}
```

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: @tadman they are not using the obsolete mysql interface.  They are using mysqli.  And can you cite a source for the procedural style being obsolete for mysqli?  I don't see that in the docs anywhere and it should just be personal preference.

Comment: @really_operator Both are supported, but I've seen an alarming number of questions where a missing `i` has completely broken the code, and additionally it gets ridiculously verbose when doing certain operations involving prepared statements. There's really no reason to use the legacy style in modern code.

Comment: I can't edit my comment, but I wanted to add that even the PHP docs say you can use either and it's entirely personal preference.  It says, verbatim, "There are no significant performance differences between the two interfaces. Users can base their choice on personal preference."  You can read more here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php

Comment: @really_operator This is true, but if you compare procedural code to the object-oriented version, the latter is consistently more minimal and readable. It's also harder to mess up the arguments, there's fewer arguments involved, and so on. `mysqli`'s procedural interface is intended to be as `mysql_query`-like as possible, and this is not a good thing at all. That interface was so terrible PHP launched it into the sun.

Comment: That sounds like your preference.  Which is the entire point of having both, you can choose one but that doesn't mean it's the correct choice for everyone.  They did not take procedural style and "launch it into the sun".  That's why it's still supported and mentioned in all the docs.  But I don't think people should be told the procedural style should not be used, there's no reason to use it, and it's deprecated when it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mysqli_fetch_array` function only fetches one result, so you don't need to loop over it with a `foreach`.  You just need to loop over each result.  You should also use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to get an associative array.  Try something similar to this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $for_php_mailer .='
       <td>'.$row['Detail_ShipDate'].'</td>
       <td>'.$row['Order_Number'].'</td>
       <td>'.$row['ShipTo_Name'].'</td>
       <td>'.$row['Status'].'</td>';
}
```

Also make sure you are using the concatenation assignment operator `.=` to keep appending results instead of overwriting the `$for_php_mailer` variable.

See the docs for more info on `myqsli_fetch_array`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

See the docs for more info on `myqsli_fetch_assoc`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: I tried this but i'm still only getting 1 record. Also if i try .= i dont get any records.

Comment: Can you dump the output to what you are getting?  Something like `$r = []; while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { $r[] = $row; } var_dump($r);`

Comment: Ok your original code worked, it was an error on my side. Now i'm still in the same position, i dont have any borders on the table. It still looks like this https://ibb.co/dGTvPsG

Comment: That looks like it would be a styling fix.  The table border property is not supported by html5 and is modified with CSS.  For example, `table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; }` Do you have CSS on the page?

Comment: Thank you sir, that was it! The .= and border!